# How do I make Intent Slots dynamic?

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to make my intent slots dynamic allowing users to say anything for the slot.

---

**Example:**

**Alexa Skill:** *What is your email address*

**User:** *my email is example@example.com*

**Alexa Skill:** *Just to confirm, your email is, example@example.com.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [AMAZON.SearchQuery](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/slot-type-reference.html#amazonsearchquery) Slot Type to capture whatever user say in your endpoint.It will capture the whole phrase that the user said and then you can apply your business logic on it.